# How to toggle to no sort in angularjs for columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

```
<a href="#/" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
        Project
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
      </a>
```

The above column when clicked sorts in ascending and descending. I need to add no-sort as well to the above toggle click.

Comment: What do you mean by no-sort?

Comment: come back to original state or random records

Answer (score 0):

you need logic to detect a third state somehow:

```
<a href="#/" ng-click="sortBy('name')">


function sortBy(prop) {
    if (sortType === prop) { // already sorted by this property
      if (!sortReverse) { // second click
         sortReverse = true;
      } else { // 3rd click
        sortType = null;
      }
    } else {
       // initial sort set for this type
       sortType = prop;
       sortReverse = false;
    }
}
```

side note: too much logic in template is bad practice and leads to hard to maintain projects. Always minimize template logic in favor of code.